# discord.py cogs not working commands inside

Tags: discord.py

I can load cogs and run it with no error but I cannot use commands inside the cog.

main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Change bot prefix
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  bot.load_extension('commands.cog_example')
  print(f'[System] {bot.user} ready')

..skip

bot.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

commands/cog.py

```
# cog_example.py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class ExampleCog(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @commands.command()
  async def hello(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello from the cog!")

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(ExampleCog(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not awaited the loading:

main.py:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  await bot.load_extension('commands.cog_example')
  print(f'[System] {bot.user} ready')
```

cog.py:

```
async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(ExampleCog(bot))
```

For later if you want to load more than one cogs, you can use this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir('YOUR_PATH_TO_COGS'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            i += 1
            cog_name = filename[:-3]
            await bot.load_extension(f'DIRECTORY_OF_COGS.{cog_name}')
    print(f"Loaded {i} cogs")
```

This function simply goes to the cogs folder and goes through the files and check if they are python files. If they are then it loads them.

Change YOUR_PATH_TO_COGS to the path which goes to your cogs folder.

Change DIRECTORY_OF_COGS to the name of the folder you keep your cogs in.